# Identifying wireless receivers

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, usb

Through the years I've managed to gather a pile of those small wireless USB receivers that wireless mice and keyboards etc use. Is there any way to plug them in and identify what they are for so I don't throw away anything important?

Comment: Try [this little tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) ... on Linux you could use `lsusb` instead. If the device is recognized by Windows you should see a meaningful string with the aforementioned tool. Make sure to refresh after plugging in each dongle.

Comment: Plug them in and check Device Manager for information on it.